# Running sudo command via CGI (Python)

Tags: python, cgi, sudo

I am writing a test suite for a web application using Selenium.

In the course of which I need to test behaviour of the app in case a certain service is running or not.

I wanted to create a cgi call to a Python script turning that service on and off.

I know that the cgi call is in the context of the webserver (Apache) however thought that issuing sudo calls like so:

```
import subprocess
import os
command = 'sudo -S launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.daemon.plist'
pwd = 'pwd123'
test1 = subprocess.Popen( command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
test1.communicate(input=pwd)
test2 = os.system( 'echo %s|%s' % (pwd,command) )
```

would do the trick, well they don't I get return code 256.

What can I do to have this call be executed w/o touching the context in which Apache runs?

As for security: this will only run on a test machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that Apache runs as needs to be in the /etc/sudoers file, or belong to the sudo group, which I guess it usually doesn't. You also need to make it not ask for a password, which is configured in /etc/sudoers

For Ubuntu, check these out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line

https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password

Comment: Bingo, the user running apache wasn't in the sudoer group. That did the trick. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It could potentially be a pathing issue..

Have you tried writing out the full path like this:

```
command = '/usr/bin/sudo -S launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.daemon.plist'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the command just worked fine on command line so it wasn't that.

Answer (score 1):

command should be a list, not a string. Try with:

```
command = ['sudo', '-S', 'launchctl', 'unload', '/Library/LaunchAgents/com.my.daemon.plist']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the command just worked fine on command line so it wasn't that.

Answer (score 0):

Cant run sudo this way -- sudo needs a controlling terminal to run.